# Bug on checkboxes in laravel livewire

Tags: laravel, debugging, checkbox, eloquent, laravel-livewire

I'm having a doble problems with my checkboxes on livewire component.

I'm trying to save in my form's table two checkboxes. This checkboxes take their value in an other table named "Garde_type".
Checkbox "home"  save in my form's table the ID 1, checkbox "visit" save ID 2.
Here all is simple...but

Laravel livewire ask me property rules to save my data. Ok ! But when i put in rules my 2 checkboxes : in my form the checkbox can't be checked..when i check them they check/uncheck immediately = first problem.
Second problem : no matter check/uncheck...everytime i submit my form, the 2 checkboxes are consider "checked" and then saved in my DB.

Here you can take a look to my code, i tried many things but i have no idea any more.

**This is the livewire component "controler" :**

```
class VilleSelect extends Component {     

public $visit;
public $home;
public $user_id;

protected function rules() {

 return [     
    
   'visit' => 'nullable',
   'home' => 'nullable',
];
    }


public function submit() {

   $annonces=annonces::create([
        'home' => $this->home->id,
        'visit' => $this->visit->id,
    ]);
    
    $annonces->save();
       
}
```

This is the checkboxes :

```
 <div class="mt-4 space-y-4">
     <div class="flex items-start">
          <div class="flex h-5 items-center">
            <x-jet-input wire:model="home" value="{{$home->id}}" type="checkbox"/>
          </div>
          <div class="ml-3 text-sm">
            <x-jet-label for="home" value="{{$home->garde_type}}"/>
          </div>
      </div>
      <div class="flex items-start">
          <div class="flex h-5 items-center">
            <x-jet-input wire:model='visit' value="{{$visit->id}}" type="checkbox"/>
          </div>
                
          <div class="ml-3 text-sm">
            <x-jet-label for="visit" value="{{$visit->garde_type}}"/>
          </div>
       </div>               
  </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

When calling your properties there is no reason to call the id specifically as you ae setting home and visit to the ID already.

Try

```php
$annonces=annonces::create([
    'home' => $this->home,
    'visit' => $this->visit,
]);
```

Comment: Well i tried this at the begining but laravel send me the all rows of the table. I need to do this to send only the ID. But maybe it's another part of the code that is a problem ? Just before the create method i write that $home = Garde_type::find(1).  Do you think that is enough for laravel to understand that i wanted the first ID of the table and only the ID for value ? Cause it didnt worked that's why i tried to passe ->id on the create method

Answer (score 0):

Well now my checkboxes don't bug any more. But it won't work as i want to.

**This is my checkboxes :**

```
   <x-jet-input wire:model="home"  value="1" type="checkbox"/>
                                
   <x-jet-input wire:model="visit" value="2" type="checkbox"/>
```

**Here my controler :**

```
public $visit;
public $home;



public function submit()
{
 

   $annonces=annonces::create([
        
        'home' => $this->home,
        'visit' => $this->visit,
      
    ]);
   
   
   
    $annonces->save();

   }
```

But i don't want to pass the value "1" and "2" in the form.

**What i tried is that :**

```
public function submit()
{
    $this->visit = Garde_type::find(2)->id;
    $this->home = Garde_type::find(1)->id;

   $annonces=annonces::create([
        
        'home' => $this->home,
        'visit' => $this->visit,
      
    ]);
   
   
    $annonces->save();

   }
```

**And in the form :**

```
  <x-jet-input wire:model="home"  value="{{home->id}}" type="checkbox"/>
                                
   <x-jet-input wire:model="visit" value="{{visit->id}}" type="checkbox"/>
```

But all i tried doesn't worked.

Any idea?

Comment: This is not a question, people will assume its an anwer, please delete and add it back to your question.

Comment: Its another question inside the answers log

Answer (score 0):

I'm confused by your code. If you already know the ID of the Garde_type, why are you looking for it again?

For instance, setting the value to an ID and then searching your Garde_type for the ID which you already have is redundant.

```php
// Set the value with the variable $home, $visit not just home and visit.
<x-jet-input wire:model="home"  value="{{ $home->id }}" type="checkbox"/>
<x-jet-input wire:model="visit" value="{{ $visit->id }}" type="checkbox"/>
```

Why are you trying to get the ID for the Garde_type here, when you already have it?

```php
// The ID will be 2 since you're searching for a record with the ID of 2
$this->visit = Garde_type::find(2)->id;
// The ID will be 1 since you're searching for a record with the ID of 1
$this->home = Garde_type::find(1)->id;
```

What are you trying to accomplish exactly?

Comment: Hello. I though it was more secure to write this way my values. What do you think about it ?